# Visual Studio Code, como colocar o console em "tempo real"

Tags: visual-studio, console, terminal

Usava a IDE Spider. Não sei como se chama isto, mas lá tinha um console em que você pode programar em tempo real, ao digitar 1+1, por exemplo, ele retornava 2 no console. Queria colocar isso no console do Visual Studio, mas o Terminal que tem lá diz que"1+1' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo...". Como coloco esse "console em tempo real"(se alguém souber o nome disso, falar por favor) no Visual Studio

PS: Uso a linguagem Python, esqueci de colocar aqui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, atualmente eu utilizo Javascript para desenvolver meus projetos e uma solução boa para isso seria a utilização do Node.js, não sei em qual linguagem você costuma desenvolver mas é bastante útil no meu caso. Eu apenas digito `node` no terminal e ele já começa a rodar.

Comment: Eu usava o Python no Spyder.

Comment: Então basta digitar ```python``` no terminal integrado, caso tenha ele instalado em seu computador que resolverá seu problema. Você também pode criar outras abas ou abrir 2 guias ao mesmo tempo para que não perca produtividade e consiga utilizar o terminal normalmente caso precise.